# How to set limit to python dataframe column length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Can I set the limit of a column's value char legnth in py dataframe?

For example, in my CSV there are few columns which char value is more than 255 but I need to trim everything which is more than 255 characters. As the CSV is huge so I cannot do it in excel.

I tried the below:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\file.csv')
print (df1)
```

Comment: so you want to exclude the row if a column value is more than 255?

Comment: Including a minimal example would certainly help

Comment: No I just want to trim that particular value and keep only 255 chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trim the length of a given `column` to its first 255 characters with the following line:

```
df1[column] = df1[column].str[:255]
```